# Apache Beam - Dataflow : Pip install failed for package: apache-beam==2.35.0

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I try to execute an Apache Beam pipeline using Dataflow as a runner. I read data from our bigquery datawarehouse, transform it and write it back in an other table. (This is just a test and the real transform is more complexe and uses Spacy)

I try to execute the pipeline below :

**main.py**

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import setuptools

table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
    projectId='my-project',
    datasetId='my-dataset',
    tableId='my-table')

options = PipelineOptions(project="my-project", region="my-region", temp_location="my-temp-location", staging_location="my-staging-location")    

class Lower(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self, row):
    row['descriptionCleaned'] =  str(row['description']).lower()
    yield row

with beam.Pipeline(runner="DataflowRunner", options=options) as pipeline:
  soft = pipeline | "GetRows" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table_spec, gcs_location="my-gcs-location")
  truc = soft | "CalculateName" >> beam.ParDo(Lower())
  truc | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('my-bigquery', schema="SCHEMA_AUTODETECT", custom_gcs_temp_location="my-temp-location", create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED", write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND")
```

And to achieve that I just run : `python main.py`

I execute it in virtual env and I already ran `pip install apache-beam apache-beam[gcp]`

And at the end I always end up with that error and nothing happens:

```
File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['G:\\Mon Drive\\update_description_python\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', 'C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpan_5d_rg', 'apache-beam==2.35.0', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1.    

 Pip install failed for package: apache-beam==2.35.0
 Output from execution of subprocess: b"Collecting apache-beam==2.35.0\r\n  Using cached apache-beam-2.35.0.zip (2.6 MB)\r\n  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started\r\n  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'\r\nSaved c:\\users\\name\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpan_5d_rg\\apache-beam-2.35.0.zip\r\nSuccessfully downloaded apache-beam\r\n"
```

I never mentionned to install beam 2.35.0, why did it try to install it ? Do I miss something in my processing to make it run with dataflow ?

EDIT: I just tested with the wordCount example and there is the same problem..

Comment: are you trying to run this locally, as in outside of the dataflow service?

Comment: Yes, and it works fine